# CS0234 errors on all views after creating new ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMkFt.png)

After create a new project using VS 16.10 -> New .NET 5 MVC project.

With making any modification I opened _Layout.cshtml and I get a bunch of errors like,

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I also get the same error for "Security", "UI", "Webpages" and more.

I've loaded the latest stable release of the .NET 5 32/64 bit, no effect, same error.

Both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `Microsoft.NetCore.App` are in the framework section of the dependencies.

The project will compile and run, but since Razor isn't resolving namespaces correctly 99% of the Intellisense lookups fail when I try to add code to the page.

`_ViewImports.cshtml` looks like this:

```
using WebApplication1
using WebApplication1.Models
addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I tried adding `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` to the `ViewImports`, no effect. I know I'm missing a reference somewhere, but I can't figure out which and where.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening Visual Studio? Making sure VS is up to date?

Comment: Yeap, ran the latest updates, rebooted computer. It's a fresh install too from about a week ago. Also re-install the .NET 5 SDK and runtimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, originally VS 2019 was installed without ASP.NET and .NET Cross-Platform Development selected. Only .NET Desktop Development was selected. I created my ASP.NET projects without the proper modules installed. After noticing this I went back installed both missing modules however that did not fix the issue. Some linkages in the backend of VS 2019 weren't being made.

Final solution - reinstall VS 2019 with correct modules from the start (didn't try repair first). Now all the helpers, code-complete, Intellicode, it all works.